# How do I get rid of the gaps between a img and a div?

Tags: html, css

`display: block` worked for the sections that have images in them but didn't for the sections where I just have a background color. I tried different display types and adding a negative margin is no solution for me because that would break my scripts.

```
/* SECTION HOME */
#home {
  height: 100% !important;
  display: flex;
}

.sectionhome::before {
  /* setzt die richtige Höhe damit die Navbar das Bild nicht blockiert */
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  margin-top: -128px;
  height: 128px;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#homebild {
  display: block;
}

/* SECTION WIR-UEBER-UNS */
#wir-ueber-uns {
  height: 100% !important;
  display: flex;
}

.sectionwir-ueber-uns::before {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  margin-top: -80px;
  height: 80px;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#wir-ueber-unsbild {
  display: block;
}

/* SECTION AKTIONEN */
#aktionen {
  height: 100% !important;
  display: flex;
}

.sectionaktionen::before {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  margin-top: -80px;
  height: 80px;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#aktionenbild {
  display: block;
}

/* SECTION TERMINVEREINBARUNG */
#terminvereinbarung {
  height: 100% !important;
  display: flex;
}

.sectionterminvereinbarung::before {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  margin-top: -80px;
  height: 80px;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#terminvereinbarungbild {
  display: block;
}

/* SECTION INFOS */
#infos {
  height: 1200px !important;
  display: flex;
  z-index: -5;
  position: relative;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.sectioninfos::before {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  margin-top: -80px;
  height: 80px;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 6%;
}
```

Comment: Hello! Could you give us an example where we can see the problem? It's hard to pinpoint with only css. If you could make a Snippet with just the Sections where you have that issue so we can see your html and css for those affected elements

Comment: you can give margin and padding of 0 in the universal selector

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/HcJanni/kbhzjdt8/14/ here's my testing fiddle

Comment: @JannisN You want to achieve that the blue section is below the image without any gap right?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you may do is maybe you can do this at the start of your CSS.

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

That is going to get rid of all the unintended margins and spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your help but this didn't seem to do the job though.